# Why do I get an error when datatable is null?

Tags: c#, sql-server, search, datatable

I am using this code to search in a SQL Server database using C# code, but when the datatable is `null` I get an error. Please help me to solve the problem and find the solution. This is my code:

```
private void button4_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();

    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(textBox1.Text))
    {
        SqlConnection sqlconn = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=ghale;Integrated Security=True");
        SqlDataAdapter sqlcmd = new SqlDataAdapter("select * from ranandeh WHERE pelak=@ID", sqlconn);
        sqlcmd.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID", textBox1.Text);

        dt.Clear();

        sqlcmd.Fill(dt);

        if (dt!= null)
        {
            comboBox2.Text = dt.Rows[0]["name"].ToString();
        }
    }
}
```

Please see the error in the picture below:

[image]

Comment: Can you post the full error/stack trace? With applicable line.

Comment: Please Visit the pictue

Comment: Post what error you got

Comment: There is no rows in position 0 because your `DataTable` is not filled. Check your sql select. Check table for nulls before using `DataTable` data

Comment: @mohsen there is `Fill()` command.

Comment: *why I get Error while datatable is null* because its null. You can't do anything with null.

Comment: I know the database is null but i want to check if it is null not show error

Comment: your `dt` is **not** `null`, it is _empty_. Maybe you want to check for that instead of checking for `null`. After `DataTable dt = new DataTable();` your datatable is _never_ `null`.

Comment: Do you checked my answer

Answer (score 1):

This is because you attempt to get a row that doesn't exist so you must check count row of DataTable .

```
if ( dt != null &&  dt.Rows.Count> 0)
{
    comboBox2.Text = dt.Rows[0]["name"].ToString();
}
```